# What's the common pattern for sensitive attributes of Terraform resource that are only required on creation?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: I'm working on a new TF Provider using [SDKv2](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/sdkv2).

I'm adding a new [data plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_plane) resource which has a very weird API. Namely, there're some sensitive attributes (that are specific to this resource so they can't be set under `provider` block -- think about DataDog / Slack API secrets that this resource needs to interact with under the hood) I need to pass on creation that are not necessary later on (for example, even for update operation). My minimal code sample:

```
resource "foo" "bar" {
  name = "abc"
  sensitive_creds = {
     "datadog_api_secret" = "abc..."
     // might pass "slack_api_secret" instead
  }
  ...
}
```

How can I implement it in Terraform to avoid state drifts etc?

So far I can see 3 options:

1. Make a user pass it first, don't save "sensitive_creds" to TF state. Make a user set it to `sensitive_creds = {}` to avoid a state drift for the next `terraform plan` run.
2. Make a user pass it first, don't save "sensitive_creds" to TF state. Make a user add `ignore_changes = [sensitive_creds] }` to their Terraform configuration.
3. Save "sensitive_creds" to TF state and live with it since users are likely to encrypt TF state anyways.

Comment: #3 is similar to how other providers e.g. AWS currently implement this, but with the values redacted from the state such that the provider does not actually know if the value changed. It more or less "checks" if the value has changed (which means `import` will be tricky).

Comment: @MattSchuchard is it more similar to #2 then? It'd be great if you could share a link to such a resource.

Comment: The reason why I added Make a user add ignore_changes = [sensitive_creds] } is for the case where sensitive_creds are missing from TF state but are still present in main.tf so terraform plan would display a diff by default

Comment: or by redacted you mean writing the secrets but setting fake values like `REDACTED` and overriding diff func in TF Provider to ignore changes if one of the values is `REDACTED`.

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/internal/service/rds/instance.go If you remove the `password` argument after specifying it initially, then the provider does not trigger an Update or Delete/Create.

Comment: Right, so the usage patter is basically to set `password` in the target resource first in `main.tf` and then remove it from `main.tf` after running a `terraform apply`? Is it documented somewhere as an accepted pattern?

That said I found this doc which is kinda surprising to see:
> All arguments including the username and password will be stored in the raw state as plain-text.

> Note that this may show up in logs, and it will be stored in the state file.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance

Comment: Oh I see, so they still store the raw value of password in TF state, it's just there's this option to remove it from TF configuration file (main.tf).

Comment: Yeah so basically #3 but with the added bonuses of `sensitive` attribute, and that the value can be removed from the config.

Comment: FWIW (for any readers) `sensitive = true` only makes TF to redact the value in TF output, there'll be still raw value in TF state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most typical compromise is for the provider to still save the user's specified value to the state during create and then to leave it *unchanged* in the "read" operation that would normally update the state to match the remote system.

The result of this compromise is that Terraform can still detect when the user has intentionally changed the secret value in the configuration, but Terraform will *not* be able to detect changes made to the value outside of Terraform.

---

This is essentially your option 3. The Terraform provider protocol requires that the values saved to the state after create exactly match anything the user has specified in the configuration, so your first two options would violate the expected protocol and thus be declared invalid by Terraform Core.

Since you are using SDKv2, you can potentially "get away with it" because Terraform Core permits that older SDK to violate some of the rules as a pragmatic way to deal with the fact that SDKv2 was designed for older versions of Terraform and therefore doesn't implement the type system correctly, but Terraform Core will still emit warnings into its own logs noting that your provider produced an invalid result, and there may be error messages raised against downstream resources if they have configuration derived from the value of your `sensitive_creds` argument.